# Dismiss action mode on navigation

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar

I am having an button in activity and having a fragment, in fragment i am having list view and on long press i am initiation action mode. When i click the button in activity action mode should be close. 
I s there any work around for that

Below is my code to initiate action mode

```
listView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new ListView.MultiChoiceModeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position, long id, boolean checked) {
            //get the count of checkedItems in History ListView
            int checkedCount = listView.getCheckedItemCount();
            //To display the number of Items selected in Action Bar
            mode.setTitle(checkedCount + " selected");
            listViewAdapter.toggleSelection(position);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_context, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            // Respond to clicks on the actions in the CAB
            AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
            System.out.println(info);
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.context_menu_delete:
                    //To retrieve the HWDid of corresponding selected rowItem in History ListView
                    List<String> ids= new ArrayList<String>();
                    String[] idArray = new String[ids.size()];
                    //This is mainly used to Store an array with Boolean Values -  it hte ListView Item is Checked, this array stores checkedItem position and bool value
                    SparseBooleanArray checkedItems = listView.getCheckedItemPositions();
                    for(int i=0;i<checkedItems.size();i++) {
                        int checkedPosition = checkedItems.keyAt(i);
                        String hwdId = ((IndexRowItem) listViewAdapter.getItem(checkedPosition)).getHwdId();
                        ids.add(hwdId);
                    }
                    idArray=ids.toArray(idArray);
                    boolean isEntryDeleted=onDeleteEntriesInList(idArray);
                    if(isEntryDeleted){
                        refreshHistoryPage();
                    }
                    mode.finish(); // Action picked, so close the CAB
                    return true;
                case R.id.context_menu_selectAll:
                    //Do deletion here
                    return true;
                default:
                    return false;
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
            listViewAdapter.removeSelection();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

You can hold a reference to the `ActionMode` and then call its [`finish()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ActionMode.html#finish()) method to explicitly close the action mode.

The basic idea: hold a reference to the ongoing action mode, and set it to null in the destroy callback.

```
private ActionMode mActionMode;

@Override public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
    ...
    mActionMode = mode;
    return true;
}

@Override public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
    ...
    mActionMode = null;
}
```

Then in your click listener, check if the action mode is non-null, and if so, finish it. Any other logic can go after that.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mActionMode != null) mActionMode.finish();
        ...
    }
});
```

Comment: I am initiating the action mode in fragment. but my button is in Activity

Comment: @Suresh: Right. Then just define a [(callback) interface to have the activity and fragment communicate to each other](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html), allowing you to propagate the call from on to the other.

Comment: Is there any work around to dismiss while clicking on any other view, other than fragment

Comment: @Suresh: Not that I know of. The closest thing I can think of is to route all click actions through a central click listener and apply above logic there (or create a proxy class for this purpose).

Comment: We achieved it by finishing the action mode bar in fragment onStop()

Comment: @Suresh: I see. That may work in your specific use case scenario, but it's not a generic solution. Any button click that doesn't affect the fragment life cycle will still leave the action mode active. I imagine that in your case the button navigates the user away from the current content?

Answer (score 0):

Use [onSupportActionModeStarted](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html#onSupportActionModeStarted(android.support.v7.view.ActionMode)) to get notified.